# Deleting a file from Google Cloud using fsspec

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fsspec

I am currently using `fsspec` in order to read and write files to my google cloud buckets with the code as shown below:

```
with fs.open(gcs_file_tmp, "rb") as fp:
    gcs_file_content = fp.read()
```

Now I want to remove a file from a GCS bucket, but I cannot seem to find the code for it. Reading the documentation [here](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), it seems as though there are some `rm` based functions and also some `delete` functions but they don't seem to work as they cannot be called as such `fs.rm(...)` or so

Comment: Please include more code of the operations you are trying to perform. I can confirm that GCSFileSystem.rm is designed for deleting files stored in a GCS bucket.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.open()` returns [fsspec.core.OpenFile](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.core.OpenFile) instance, having `fs` property.
When you open GCS file, `fs` is [GCSFileSystem](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gcsfs.core.GCSFileSystem).
When you open local file, `fs` is [LocalFileSystem](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.local.LocalFileSystem).
I understand fsspec absorbs difference between file systems, as class [AbstractFileSystem](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem).
We can call `delete()` of it.

In this way, we should pass target file path again(we can use `path` property if you like).

```py
# for GCS
f = fsspec.open("gs://bucketHoge/fuga.txt")
f.fs.delete(f.path)

# for local
f = fsspec.open("/tmp/fuga.txt")
f.fs.delete(f.path)
```

I wonder there is a better way...